# Facebook API: Is it possible to post to a 'Closed' Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a valid access token to my account which has both `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` permissions and I tested the app to publish in open/public groups and it works just fine.

The `user_managed_groups` permission should enable me to publish in other groups that are not public as stated in [Facebook developers reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/feed):

> For all other kinds of groups, a user access token with publish_actions and user_managed_groups permission is required for someone able to post to the group.

However, as I try to publish in closed groups it returns an error: `(#200) The user has not authorized the application to perform this action.`

My question is:
Is it possible to post to a closed facebook group vai API?
Do I have to "Review" the app to get `user_managed_groups` permission as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_managed_groups)? Even though my app is intended to be used by me only and not willing to publish it to the outside world?.
Or is this a bug in Facebook group permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you admin/mod of the group? If not, afaik it is not possible to post to closed groups. Try as group admin, the permissions are correct (`user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions`).

Comment: I'm not a admin...I tried on a group that I have admin privileges to and indeed it worked.
However, I am a bit confused given the quote in my question, it seems it should be possible...can you point me to the documentation part stating that it's not possible to post to closed groups?

I mean facebook clearly states that it's not possible to create events through the API for example, is there somewhere they state something similar for posting in closed groups?

Comment: i don´t know about any docs about this, but it has been discussed several times on stackoverflow, that´s why i know it. it´s for a good reason, there is/was a lot of spam in groups and no regular user should be able to post to groups via app if he is not admin. i can´t think of any serious use case for this, to be honest.